# JavaScript in datatables pages

Tags: javascript, datatables, symfony-2.8

Actually I'm working with the next datatable:
[Datatabel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEBpl.png)

```
<table aria-describedby="dataTable_info" cellspacing="0" class="table table-hover dataTable" id="dataTable" role="grid" style="width:100%;" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>{{'fsaGeneralPlan.table.Auditors'|trans({}, 'FSABundle')}}</th>
                                <th>{{'fsaGeneralPlan.table.Audits'|trans({}, 'FSABundle')}}</th>
                                <th>{{'fsaGeneralPlan.table.Areas'|trans({}, 'FSABundle')}}</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% for audit in auditsByArea %}
                            {% set myArray = audit.Audits|split(',') %}
                            {% set AuditsStatus = audit.AuditsStatus|split(',') %}
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{ audit.Auditor }}</td>
                                        <td>
                                        {# {% set long = numberOfAudits|length + 2  %} #}
                                        {# <h1>{{ long }}</h1> #}
                                            {% for i in 0..3 %}
                                            {% set e = i + 1 %}
                                            <a  title="{{ AuditsStatus[i] }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#auditModal" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm auditButton {{ AuditsStatus[i] }}" data-id="Audit{{ myArray[i] }}" data-area="{{ audit.area_name }}"  data-status="{{ AuditsStatus[i] }}" id="auditButton{{ myArray[i] }}" name="auditButton">{{'w' ~ e }}</a>

                                            {# <input  class ="auditButton {{ AuditsStatus[i] }} mx-2" value="{{'W' ~ i }}" href="" data-id="Audit{{ myArray[i] }}" data-area="{{ audit.area_name }}" data-status="{{ AuditsStatus[i] }}" id="auditButton{{ myArray[i] }}" name="auditButton" type='text' readonly ></input> #}
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </td>
                                        <td>{{ audit.area_name }}</td>
                                    </tr> 
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

In that table every square,is a button to open a modal when the button is clicked.
To do this I use a java script to open the modal:

```
    $(function () {
                    $('.auditButton').on('click',function(){
                        //activar modal de waiting
                        $('#waitingModal').modal('show');
     });
```

The problem is that it just works when I clicked any AuditButton of the first page of the Datatable.

If I change the page in the datatable and I click one button it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When attaching events to cells in a table controlled by DataTables, you need to be careful how it is done. Because DataTables removes nodes from the DOM, events applied with a static event listener might not be able to bind themselves to all nodes in the table. To overcome this, simply use jQuery delegated event listener options link : https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html

Comment: thaaanks it works, but If I click the button I juste get the properties of the button like: <a title="button"  class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-id="Audit20"> </a> How can I get just the value of data-id ?